# How to apply a different `\titlespacing` for table of contents/list of figures/list of tables?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, chapters, titlesec

I am trying to apply a `\titlespacing` to my chapter titles by doing something like

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{50pt}
```

However, this messes up the title spacing for table of contents, list of figures, and list of tables (which I guess are also considered `\chapter`?), where I would prefer something like

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}
```

---

How do I apply a specific `\titlespacing` to the `\tableofcontents`, `\listoftables`, and `\listoffigures` commands, while having a different `\titlespacing' for all my other chapters?